# knockoutjs - data-bind visible

Tags: jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm studying Knockoutjs and I'm doing some low-level experiments.

Following an existing jsFiddle ko sample I updated it adding another element binding it with visible.

Follow this link: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/215/

I want to see the last paragraph only when the computed strings.length are > than 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your definition of fullName:

```
return viewModel.firstName() + " " + viewModel.lastName();
```

As you've defined it, fullName is *always* at least length 1 because of the space. If you change > 0 to > 1 it works fine.

Comment: A cleaner solution might even be to add a `hasName` method, which `return this.firstName().length > 0 || this.lastName().length > 0`, or `return this.fullName().trim().length > 0`.